# Can you put a ui button inside of a ui accordion?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using a jquery ui accordion to contain a jstree.  I want to add a dropdown menu to provide a set of options to the user.  Since I'm using a jquery ui theme, I thought it would be a good idea to use the jquery ui button/menu to create the dropdown.

[jQuery ui Menu](http://blog.jqueryui.com/2010/06/jquery-ui-19m2-menu/)

When I render my page, the button has been completely removed from the DOM. Using the stripped down version of the html below as a reference, the jsTreeOptionsMenu div would still be in the DOM but all of its contents would be gone.

Has anyone run into this before?

```
<div id="accordion">
<h3><a href="">FIRST</a></h3>
<div id="jsTreeArea">
    <div id="jsTreeTarget"></div>
    <div id="jsTreeOptionsMenu">
        <button>Options Menu</button>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">menu link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">menu link 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<h3><a href="">SECOND</a></h3>
<div>
    content
</div>
```

And here's the js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#jsTreeOptionsMenu button").button({
            icons: {
                primary: null,
                secondary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
            }
        }).each(function () {
            $(this).next().menu({
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    $(this).hide();
                },
                input: $(this)
            }).hide();
        }).click(function (event) {
            var menu = $(this).next();
            if (menu.is(":visible")) {
                menu.hide();
                return false;
            }
            menu.menu("deactivate").show().css({ bottom: 0, right: 0 }).position({
                my: "left top",
                at: "right top",
                of: this
            });
            $(document).one("click", function () {
                menu.hide();
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure the jstree plugin does not remove the markup ?

Comment: I removed the reference to the jstree and the button markup remained in the DOM.  I hadn't thought of that being the problem.  Unfortunately, I'm left with the same result - my jquery button/menu is getting blown away by another jquery plugin.  Is this a know issue?  Is there a workaround?

Comment: I don't think it can be considered as an issue. I guess it's just the way the jstree plugin is designed: it clears the content prior to constructing the tree (it's just a guess). What are trying to achieve exactly with those buttons in the tree ?

Comment: The button isn't in the tree but rather in a separate container div below the tree.  I would understand if the tree removed the container.  It doesn't make any sense that it leaves the container and removes the contents.  Also, in my first iteration, I used a roll-your-own dropdown that was not affected by the tree.    

To answer the last part of your question, the dropdown will offer users actions such as "add a new folder."

Comment: Seems odd indeed. And you apply the jstree on "jsTreeTarget" or "jsTreeArea" ?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific in my original post.  I apply the tree on jsTreeTarget.

Comment: It's ok. Then I just don't understand why the jstree plugin messes up the other container :-/ Any option you might be passing to the jstree that might corrupt the button container ?

Comment: You question helped me focus more clearly on the issue.  I'm using jquery.loadmask.js to apply an overlay on the treeArea.  My button is being removed during the unmaskElement event.  Now that I know where it's happening, I can code a work around.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hope you'll figure out some workaround. Glad it helped.